# Renew wildcard certificate fails with »None of the preferred challenges are supported by the selected plugin.«

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, certbot-dns-plugin

I have a Let's Encrypt wildcard certificate which was obtained with the DNS challenge.
In the meantime I migrated the webapp and the certificate to a new server, where renewing that certificate fails.

```
$ certbot renew  --preferred-challenges dns --standalone
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/dedacted.de-0001.conf
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Cert is due for renewal, auto-renewing...
Plugins selected: Authenticator standalone, Installer nginx
Renewing an existing certificate
Performing the following challenges:
Attempting to renew cert (dedacted.de-0001) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/dedacted.de-0001.conf produced an unexpected error: None of the preferred challenges are supported by the selected plugin. Skipping.
```

These is the config file:

```
# renew_before_expiry = 30 days
version = 0.40.0
archive_dir = /etc/letsencrypt/archive/dedacted.de-0001
cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dedacted.de-0001/cert.pem
privkey = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dedacted.de-0001/privkey.pem
chain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dedacted.de-0001/chain.pem
fullchain = /etc/letsencrypt/live/dedacted.de-0001/fullchain.pem

# Options used in the renewal process
[renewalparams]
account = dedacted
authenticator = nginx
server = https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
installer = nginx
```

I tried different options for the renewing command but had no success.

This is the last debug log:

```
2021-12-14 11:10:00,631:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:
HTTP 200
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 14 Dec 2021 10:10:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 384
Connection: keep-alive
Boulder-Requester: 110278569
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, no-cache
Link: <https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory>;rel="index"
Replay-Nonce: dedacted
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=604800

{
  "identifier": {
    "type": "dns",
    "value": "dedacted.de"
  },
  "status": "pending",
  "expires": "2021-12-20T14:57:56Z",
  "challenges": [
    {
      "type": "dns-01",
      "status": "pending",
      "url": "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/acme/chall-v3/dedacted/dedacted",
      "token": "dedacted"
    }
  ],
  "wildcard": true
}
2021-12-14 11:10:00,632:DEBUG:acme.client:Storing nonce: dedacted
2021-12-14 11:10:00,632:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Performing the following challenges:
2021-12-14 11:10:00,632:WARNING:certbot.renewal:Attempting to renew cert (dedacted.de-0001) from /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/dedacted.de-0001.conf produced an unexpected error: None of the preferred challenges are supported by the selected plugin. Skipping.
2021-12-14 11:10:00,635:DEBUG:certbot.renewal:Traceback was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 462, in handle_renewal_request
    main.renew_cert(lineage_config, plugins, renewal_candidate)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 1208, in renew_cert
    renewed_lineage = _get_and_save_cert(le_client, config, lineage=lineage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/main.py", line 116, in _get_and_save_cert
    renewal.renew_cert(config, domains, le_client, lineage)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/renewal.py", line 320, in renew_cert
    new_cert, new_chain, new_key, _ = le_client.obtain_certificate(domains, new_key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 348, in obtain_certificate
    orderr = self._get_order_and_authorizations(csr.data, self.config.allow_subset_of_names)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/client.py", line 396, in _get_order_and_authorizations
    authzr = self.auth_handler.handle_authorizations(orderr, best_effort)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 62, in handle_authorizations
    achalls = self._choose_challenges(authzrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 206, in _choose_challenges
    self._get_chall_pref(authzr.body.identifier.value),
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/certbot/auth_handler.py", line 229, in _get_chall_pref
    raise errors.AuthorizationError(
certbot.errors.AuthorizationError: None of the preferred challenges are supported by the selected plugin
```

Did I miss to install something for supporting wildcard certificated or did something change and it is not supported anymore the way it was?

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is what I can tell from what you are doing. You already had a working certificate that was generated using the `certbot nginx` plugin. Now, you've relocated your server and config to a new server and want to renew the certificate. My advice is to use the nginx plugin again by adding `--nginx` to your command for the renewal. I suspect that because it is not included, certbot is raising the error of the plugin used is not supported.

If that does not work, I will suggest that you remove the old configuration you copied onto the new server and run certbot to create a new certificate with its own config for you.